# AMPPS as a production server?

Tags: apache, scripting, wamp, softaculous

Since [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com) has [Softaculous](http://www.softaculous.com). I was thinking of using AMPPS as a production server. I know it is meant for development purpose only. What can be the risk, I want to know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With packages like this, the default is often "everything on" to allow people with little experience to go download it and get wordpress,silverstripe etc up and running as fast as they can.

For production servers, the recommended way to go about things is the other way round, just enabling the things you ned to get the job done and turning off the rest. If you've 35 apache modules and 26 php modules running then that's a lot of extra code to slow your server down and expose more vulnerabilities. More software running means more patching, more watching for holes and sometimes less in terms of performance.

Think of these packages like ampps and mamp as playgrounds for coders. You could deploy them on a production server and they would most likely be fine but stable networks and secure systems require a more vigilant approach to building a production web server.

Once you've built your application, if you can find out what are its minimum requirements are in terms of apache php etc and then install just what it needs, you might find it more manageable in the long run.

It's convenience vs security as ever!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's intended to be used for actual servers, and I see no reason why you shouldn't. It's just apache, mysql, and some other stuff anyway. If you're concerned about using the bundle, just install the tools yourself, from packages or source.